# Bootstrap tooltip not working on HTML loaded using Ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, ajax, twitter-bootstrap

I am calling Bootstrap's tooltip function on an input.  The HTML code that was loaded via ajax. But I am unable to get the tooltip to load.

My ajax call inserts all the code within the "tooltiptest517" div.  It also dynamically inserts the jquery along with the html call.  I'm trying to have it so that when I hover over the input a tooltip pops up.

```
<h3 style="margin-bottom:30px;">
 <div id="tooltiptest578">
  Write the decimal as a fraction.  Give your answer in simplest form.
  <br>
  <br>
  0.78 = 
  <input data-toggle="popover" data-html="true" data-content="" data-placement="top" trigger="hover" autocomplete="off" type="text" id="blank1" class="blank1" size="5" name="answer1">
  <span id="first-input-span" data-toggle="popover" data-placement="right" data-html="true" data-content="<h4>Now you're all set to go!  Happy learning!</h4>"></span>
  <br>
  <script>$('#tooltiptest578 #blank1').tooltip({ template: '<div class="tooltip" role="tooltip"><div class="tooltip-arrow"></div><div class="tooltip-inner" style="max-width:250px;width:250px; background-color: #EFFAEA;color:black;opacity:1;border: 1px solid #5BBC2E;"></div></div>', placement: 'bottom', html: true, title : 'If your answer is a fraction, use /.<br/>For example: <i>3/4</i> or <i>-3/4</i><br/> For a mixed number, write <i>8 3/4</i> or <i>-8 3/4.</i>'});</script>
  <br>
 </div>                         
</h3>
```

This works when I don't make an ajax call but does not work when there is an ajax call.  The entire web app is using angular but I don't think that makes a difference.  I tried wrapping the tooltip call inside an ajaxComplete, function() and documentReady wrappers but that didn't work either.  Any help here would be tremendous, thank you!

Comment: you can initialize your tooltip once your ajax call is completed on success

Comment: I did that but that didn't work either.  I put the entire tooltip code in the script tag above in my success code and it still didn't work.  In fact, it didn't recognize $('#blank1') when I did that so I created $('body').on('click', '#blank1', function() {}); and put the tooltip code in there but that didn't work either.

Comment: Is there something wrong with calling the tooltip code by passing the "title", "placement", "html", "template", etc. as a parameters in the tooltip function?

Comment: I doubt it. It seems to work fine https://jsfiddle.net/sg3u0c3c/

Comment: The jsfiddle isn't pulling the input tag via AJAX.  It works when there is no ajax call involved.  But once you use AJAX to add both the jquery script and the html input tag to the file, it doesn't work.

Comment: Can you post the code for your Ajax call. the fiddle was just to show that your tooltip parameters are right

Comment: this.loadNextProblem = function()
                                 {
                                        this.problemHTML = $sce.trustAsHtml("Loading");
                                        $http.get('problempageajaxcall').success(function (data) {
                                                problemControl.getProblem = $sce.trustAsHtml(data);
                                        });

                                }

Comment: can you place the script tag outside the <div id="tooltiptest"> ? And where is blank1 present in the markup is it inside div#tooltiptest578?

Comment: yes, i tried the script tag in the document.ready outside the "<div id=\"tooltiptest\">" and you can see the blank1 in the code posted above (it's the id for the input tag inside the div#tooltiptest578.

Answer (score 0):

```
$.ajax({  
      type: "POST",  
       url: "example.php",  
       data:{  
       cache: false,  
       success: function(data){  
           $("#tableData").html(data);  
           $("[data-toggle=popover]").popover();  
        }  
      });  
 }
```